# pull out a file named to ~

Tags: rename, filenames, quoting

So I have downloaded a music album from aMule and it is located in the `.aMule/Incoming` directory. I tried to move it out with the following command:

```
 mv albumName.rar ~
```

This left me with a file `~` in `.aMule/Incoming` which I could not rename because tilde is reserved for home directory. I know I can access it via Nautilus by showing hidden files. How can I pull it out in terminal?

**Update**
This is how it looks like now

```
   manuzhang@manuzhang-R458-R457:~/.aMule/Incoming$ ls -l
   total 328
   -rw-r--r-- 1 manuzhang manuzhang 297266 2012-03-19 12:07 ～
   -rw-r--r-- 1 manuzhang manuzhang  34479 2011-10-11 19:51 [kat.ph]friends.season.1.with.english.subtitles.torrent
```

Answer (score 6):

```
mv \~ ~/albumName.rar
mv '~' ~/albumName.rar
mv ./~ ~/albumName.rar
```

You can always protect a character that has a special meaning in the shell by putting a backslash before it.

You can always tell the shell to interpret a sequence literally by putting it inside single quotes. The only character that you can't put inside such a literal string is the single quote itself, since it indicates the end of the literal string. You can use `'\''` instead; it means “end of literal, the character `'`, start of literal”, but you can think of it as a weird way of putting a single quote inside a literal string within single quotes.

The character `~` is only special at the beginning of a path, so if you put a directory indication, `~` will be the name of the file in this directory.

Note that if the file name begins with `-`, only the last of these three methods will work. This is because `-` is not special to the shell; it has a special meaning to the command: it indicates an option. Another way of protecting `-` against this special meaning is to put the special option `--` before it: `--` on a command line indicates the end of the options, only file names (or other non-option arguments) may come after it.

Note also that the command you show should have copied the file to your home directory, as the `~` character should have been interpreted by the shell. It's possible that you mistyped and created a file that's not called `~`. Run `ls -q` or `ls -Q` to see if the file name contains an unprintable character. If that doesn't provide any visual indication, try `ls | od -t o1`, which will show the octal code for each byte in the file name. In ksh, bash or zsh, you can use `$'\123'` in a command line to specify a character by its octal code. Alternatively, you may be able to find a pattern that matches the file. For example, if you determine that the length of the file name is 3, and that the only other files whose length is 2 are `foo` and `bar`, you can move the file with

```
mv ./[^bf]?? ~/albumName.rar
```

And if you're willing to use the mouse and the name is composed of printable characters that you don't know how to type: copy-paste the file name from the output of `ls`.

Comment: Note that usually only GNU tools understand `--` to mean the end of options.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Most commands do understand `--`: it's mandated by POSIX (apart from a few historical exceptions like `echo`), and it's provided by `getopt`, so pretty much any command that takes single-character options understands it.

Comment: @Gilles none of three works. `mv: cannot stat '~': No such file or directory`

Comment: @manuzhang Are you sure that your file is called `~` (with an ASCII tilde)? Is it maybe called `  ̃ ` or some other visually similar character (which would explain how you created the file in the first place: in the command you show, a tilde should have been interpreted as the home directory)?

Comment: @Gilles I'm sure it is a tilde

Comment: @manuzhang `mv` doesn't think so. What is the output of `ls`? Of `ls -q`?

Comment: @Gilles both `～  *.torrent`

Comment: That's not a tilde.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams If not, what could that be?

Comment: It's a fullwidth tilde, which means that you need to turn your IM on in order to type it.

Comment: @manuzhang This is not an ASCII tilde, but a U+FF5E FULLWIDTH TILDE, probably typed with a Chinese or Japanese input method. Either use the same input method, or copy-paste the character from the `ls` output.

Comment: what a mistake!!! Sorry, I should've thought of it myself and saved your time. Anyway, thank you guys.

Comment: @Gilles would you please explain a bit more about `$'\123'`

Answer (score 1):

Specify a path to the file.

```
cat ./~
```

Comment: `cat: ./~: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

The pasted update shows it is some high-ASCII or Unicode character, not a simple tilde... Can you use `mc` or another file manager? How about move everything *else* out of that directory, then using tab completion?

Comment: Since it's not actually a tilde the original problem ("`~` is interpreted as the user's home directory") doesn't exist. Simple copy-and-paste (or typing it in using the same IM as when it was originally typed) will work.